# How do i represent a unnamed list of objects with protobuf?

Tags: java, spring, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am trying to comsume a REST api with Spring RestTemplate, this is pretty much what i want to do:

```java
    public ResponseEntity<OfficeProto.Offices> getAllOffices() {
        return restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<OfficeProto.Offices>() {});
    }
```

The following is how the source json looks like, how do i represent a unnamed list in protobuf?

```
[
  {
    "name": "Office 1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Office 2"
  }
]
```

This is how my `.proto` file looks like

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_outer_classname = "OfficeProto";

message Office {
 string name = 1;
}

message Offices {
    repeated Office office = 1;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.findwise.connect.OfficeProto$Offices] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat$ParseException: 1:1: Expected "{".
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to consume a *general purpose* JSON API using protobuf. However, protobuf *is not* a general purpose JSON serializer - the JSON support that it has is *very opinionated*, and the opinions it has aren't a fit for your scenario.

So: don't try to use protobuf in this case. Use a more general JSON tool.

As general guidance to make life easier, you should only use protobuf as the parser if it was *written* by protobuf (and you just happened to need a text API rather than the binary API that protobuf prefers). That way, you know that the opinions will at least match.